# How to create a program that pulls the changelog of os changes live to mirror file

Tags: linux, security, changelog

I would love to be able to create a mirror file of changelog live, as if someone was attempting to hack my system, and any changes that were made, be mirrored into another file. Is there a script already created to do this?
I was thinking for linux system in particular.

Answer (score 0):

maybe [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) could work for you ?